# Передача параметров функции из переменной

Tags: javascript

Никак не удается передать параметры функции из переменной.

Пишет что массива cts не существует. Можно ли вообще таким образом передавать параметры?

```
    $('.fb').click(function () {
    var a = $(this).attr('data-fb');
    var cts = $(this).attr('data-cts').split(',');
    alert(cts.length);
    if ( a == 'front') {
        $('#canvas').parent().show();
        $('#canvas_back').parent().hide();

        // Переопределение переменных с канвой
        buffCan = can;
        can = can_back;
        can_back = buffCan;

        // Вызов функций
        addImg(сts[0], cts[1], cts[2], cts[3]);

    } else if ( a == 'back') {
        $('#canvas').parent().hide();
        $('#canvas_back').parent().show();

        // Переопределение переменных с канвой
        buffCan = can;
        can = can_back;
        can_back = buffCan;

        // Вызов функций
        addImg(сts[0], cts[1], cts[2], cts[3]);

    }
});

    function addImg (w,h,t,l) {

    var b = can.getObjects().length;

    if (b > 0) {
        for (var i = b; i >= 0; i--) {
            removeObj(i);
        }
    }

    width = w;
    height = h;
    left_b = l;
    top_b = t;

    window.clipRect1 = new fabric.Rect({
        angle: 0,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        left: l,
        top: t,
        width: w,
        height: h,
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', /* use transparent for no fill */
        stroke: '#DDD',
        strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
        selectable: false
    });

    clipRect1.set({
        clipFor: 'clip'
    });

    can.add(clipRect1);

    function findByClipName(name) {
        return _(can.getObjects()).where({
            clipFor: name
        }).first()
    }

    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    clipByName = function (ctx) {
        this.setCoords();
        var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);
        var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
        var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
        ctx.save();

        var ctxLeft = -( this.width / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxTop = -( this.height / 2 ) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxWidth = clipRect.width - clipRect.strokeWidth;
        var ctxHeight = clipRect.height - clipRect.strokeWidth;

        ctx.translate( ctxLeft, ctxTop );

        ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
        ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(
            clipRect.left - this.oCoords.tl.x,
            clipRect.top - this.oCoords.tl.y,
            clipRect.width,
            clipRect.height
        );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: можно так передавать, но без кода тут вряд ли смогут помочь

Comment: Добавил участок кода. С массивом проблем нет, я проверил все переменные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас опечатка в `сts[0]`. Вероятно русская `с` ;)

Comment: Вот это поворотO_O Я уж думал что кто-то свыше не хочет чтоб я дописал код. Спасибо!)